# zsh expansion modifiers in scripts

Tags: shell-script, zsh

I've just found out that ZSH's modifiers only work in interactive scripts, so the following will work correctly on the command line but not from a script (the script ignores the modifier and echoes the whole path).

```
for file in ~/folder/*; do
  echo ${file:t}
done
```

How can I manipulate parameters in this way from an executed script file?

Comment: Where did you hear that? It works for me, as long as I make sure to execute the shell script with zsh.

Comment: @DyslexicTangent Ok, I had assumed that a `source` command from a `.zshrc` file would be interpreted using `zsh`. When I add the shebang it all works as expected, my bad. Add it as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, just make sure that you're executing the script with zsh.